# Placing the TextView directly on top of the Imageview on XML

Tags: android, layout

Right now the textview comes first on a vertically and next is the imageview. How could I make it so that the textview superimpose on top of the textview on XML? textview have higher Z order than imageview.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TableLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="0px"
android:padding="0px">
<TextView android:id="@+id/textItem"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="#AA000000"
android:textColor="#ffffffff"
android:textSize="22sp" 
android:text="Find Now"
android:enabled="false"
>
</TextView>
 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/myImageView0"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/bar_top"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possible solution is remove table layout and use the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/textItem"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="#AA000000"
android:textColor="#ffffffff"
android:textSize="22sp" 
android:text="Find Now"
android:enabled="false"
>
</TextView>
 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/myImageView0"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textItem"
android:src="@drawable/bar_top"/> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

another solution if you need table layout for some other purpose is to use framelayout whose content will be a textview and imageview and add it as a cell of tablelayout

Answer (score 1):

Remove the TableLayout it should be on top of each other. You can than easily change the position by a lot of differen `android:layout_...` attributes